# (swift) Anyone can help me to make bulk change to those buttons?

Tags: swift

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTcXO.png)

when user get into this page, I want to change the background of those button.
for example, when the level of user is 6, I want to change the top 6 background of buttons to a blue picture as first button. I don't wanna write a code one by one, so please help me to write a function, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add you buttons to the array in order of increasing level and do something like this:

```
var buttons: [UIButton] // array of your buttons, next you need to init it
...
func setColorForUserLevel(userLevel: Int) {
    if userLevel > buttons.count {
        return
    } else {
        for i in 0...userLevel - 1 {
            buttons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }
}
```

I create simple example project to show how to use it:

1. I have outlets with `UIButton!` type and `buttons` object in code:
   [image]
2. And i test `setColorForUserLevel` function in `viewDidLoad` method:

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       buttons = [button1, button2, button3]
       setColorForUserLevel(2)
   }

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var LevelOutlet2: UIButton!               
    
    var buttons: [UIButton] = [LevelOutlet2]                                                           I have a problem with init.   Xcode tell me controller.type does not have a member 'LevelOutlet2'

Comment: Change `var buttons` to `@IBOutlet var add: [UIButton]!` and connect all buttons to this collection. Run a loop to change what you want.

Comment: It's really helpful, Thank you very much!